# Javascript - Identifying Positive 0 and negative 0 numbers

Tags: javascript, zero

I have a requirement where i have to identify if the number is a positive `0` or a negative `0` and do color coding for those numbers. This is applicable only for `0`s and not greater or lesser than `0`.

i.e.:

1. `0.00000983` (Positive Zero)
2. `-0.0000343` (Negative Zero)

I tried below method but this does not help for values having decimals with `0`. Please guide.

```
function isMinusZero(value) {
  return 1/value === -Infinity;
}

isMinusZero(0); // false
isMinusZero(-0); // true
```

Comment: And, what wrong with your solution?

Comment: does not work for 0.0000098 or any such number

Comment: but `0.00000983` is not any zero, I don't understand the requirement as you've stated it ... clearly that number is not zero

Comment: Bravo - requirement was anything greater than 0 but less than 1 i had to show positive green. anything less than 0 but greater than -1 i need to show as -0.

Comment: Usually in computers 0 is zero with sign bit turned off, meaning that zero is a non-negative thing. If you turn it on, you will get smallest negative integer. So you can't differentiate `+0` from `-0` in the form of _number_. In math you can approach 0 from either side of natural numbers, so sign doesn't have much sense for zero itself. You need to assign 0 to `-` or `+` domain **explicitly**, so you can't differentiate `+0` from `-0` in math either - just approaching it. Thus your requirements doesn't have much sense

Comment: Besides technically your output **is not zero** at all, because it doesn't follow multiplicative property of zero : `(+1)*0 ≠ (-1)*0` in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```js
function isMinusZero(value) {
  if (Object.is(value, -0)) return true;   // handles OP's specific requirement
  if (value === 0) return false;
  return 1/Math.abs(Math.ceil(value)) === Infinity;
}

console.log(isMinusZero(1234)); // false
console.log(isMinusZero(-1223)); // false
console.log(isMinusZero(0)); // false
console.log(isMinusZero(-0)); // true
console.log(isMinusZero(0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000976767)); // false
console.log(isMinusZero(-0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000967676767)); // true
console.log(isMinusZero(-0.0000000000003400003400000000000000034000000000967676767)); // true
```

References:

- [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)
- [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)
- [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)
- [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for [`Math.sign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)

- If the argument is positive, returns 1.
- If the argument is negative, returns -1.
- If the argument is positive zero, returns 0.
- If the argument is negative zero, returns -0.
- Otherwise, NaN is returned.

Comment: It would be nice to demonstrate the OP with an example in the posted function.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is):

```js
function isMinusZero(value) {
  return Object.is(-0, value);
}

console.log(
  isMinusZero(0), // false
  isMinusZero(-0) // true
)
```

Comment: Cool, but cannot be used to test 0.0000000009 === 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.sign()`

```js
function isZeroSign(value){

return   Math.sign(value) > 0 ;

}

console.log(isZeroSign(0.00022));
console.log(isZeroSign(-0.0033));
console.log(isZeroSign(5500));
console.log(isZeroSign(-0.000000000000000000000000041))
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is your solution

```js
function isMinusZero(value) {
  return value.toString().startsWith("-");
}
console.log(
  isMinusZero(0), // false
  isMinusZero(-0) // true
)
```

.

Comment: `isMinusZero(-0)` returns `false`, because (-0).toString() is just "0"

Comment: I made you a snippet. It returns false,false